# REGEX specific word from Name

Tags: c#, regex, validation, tableau-api, regexp-replace

I am trying to figure out regex for wrongly formated names where the user has entered in the name and the relationship as one value, for example

`[Son of Joseph Joestar ] => s/o. Joseph Joestar`

the problem is since there was no validation, the users entered different variations like

s/o , s/, s/Joseph... , etc

this is so far I have gotten

```
^(s\/o.)(S\/o.)(s\/o)(S\/o)(s\/)(S\/)\w+
```

1. the relation is at the beginning or at the start, and after that is the name
2. there are 3 more cases Daughter(D/o.), Wife(W/o.), Father(F/o.)

I want to know the corresponding REGEX to filter out the relation prefixes

Thank You In advance

Comment: what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe start with something like that

```
string foo = "s/o. Joseph Joestar";

// Look (and capture) for SDWF followed by "/" and 
// EITHER "o" and maybe "." and maybe a white space
// OR we look ahead (?=  ) and see a Upper wordchar followeed by lower word chars.
//   look ahead because we do not want to have anything to do with this when replacing
string bar = Regex.Replace(foo, @"^([sSdDwWfF])/(o\.?\s?|(?=[A-Z]\w+))", match =>
{
    string relation = match.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() switch
    {
        "S" => "Son of",
        "D" => "Daughter of",
        "F" => "Father of",
        "W" => "Wife of",
        _ => throw new Exception("Oops")
    };
    return $"{relation} ";
});
```